# User Sign Up Test: RuntimeError: not a redirect! 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

What does this error mean and how do I fix this?

It works on the application but when I do the  `rails test` , these are the errors I have received:

This is what the error shows when I do the `rails test`:

> UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup_information: RuntimeError: not a
> redirect! 422 Unprocessable Entity
> test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:18:in `block in class:UsersSignupTest'

**test-integration-user_sign_up.test**

```
require "test_helper"

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
    post users_path, params: { user: { name: "",
    
    email: "user@invalid",
    password: "foo",
    password_confirmation: "bar" } }
    
    end
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

  test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
    post users_path, params: { user: { name: "Example User",
    email: "user@example.com",
    password: "password",
    password_confirmation: "password" } }
    
    end
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
end
```

**session_controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
 
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user&.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
        # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
      # Create an error message.
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  
  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end


require "test_helper"

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get new" do
    get login_path
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

**user-controller**

```
require "test_helper"

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = users(:manon)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get users_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get signup_path
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create user" do
    assert_difference("User.count") do
      post users_url, params: { user: { email: "user@example.com", name: "Example User", password: "thisfoobar", password_confirmation:"thisfoobar"} }
    end

    assert_redirected_to user_url(User.last)
  end

  test "should show user" do
    get user_url(@user)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_user_url(@user)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update user" do
    patch user_url(@user), params: { user: { email: @user.email, name: @user.name, password: "thisfoobar", password_confirmation: "thisfoobar"  } }
    assert_redirected_to user_url(@user)
  end

  test "should destroy user" do
    assert_difference("User.count", -1) do
      delete user_url(@user)
    end

    assert_redirected_to users_url
  end

end
```

**user-model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :microposts
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
    uniqueness: true
    
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

    # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
    def User.digest(string)
        cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
        BCrypt::Engine.cost
        BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end
end
```

**session-helper**

```
module SessionsHelper
    # Logs in the given user.
    def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
    def current_user
        if session[:user_id]
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
        end
    end

   # Logs out the current user.
    def log_out
        session.delete(:user_id)
        @current_user = nil
    end
end
```

**fixture**

```
manon:
  name: manon
  email: manon@email.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is not redirecting on unsuccessful form submission - nor should it. In the Rails conventions you render the `new` view again and send it as the response body together with a 422 - Unprocessable Entity status code.

So the test helpers will rightfully raise an error since the status code is not one that should cause a redirect and there is no `LOCATION` header.

Your test should actually look like:

```ruby
require "test_helper"

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, 
           params: { 
             user: { 
               name: "",
               email: "user@invalid",
               password: "foo",
               password_confirmation: "bar" 
            } 
          }
    end
    assert_template :new 
    refute is_logged_in?
  end
  # ...
end
```

But since you're not testing an API application here I would consider [creating a system test](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing) instead to test this from the users POV. It provides a lot more value then a simple integration test as it will test the view at the same.